# Can you add getters and setters to a Hibernate entity that are ignored for serialization?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am working with an entity class and I understand there's a mapping between Java class fields and database columns. What I don't understand is that if I want to add a getX method that is basically a property derived from other fields (e.g. to get the same information as an existing field but in a different format), I seem to get Hibernate exceptions at runtime complaining that there's no corresponding setter.

Is there something I can do, perhaps some annotation I can put on a method in an entity class to essentially tell Hibernate "ignore this method, it's none of your business"?

Comment: `@Transient`...

Answer (score 2):

Use `@Transient` over the getter method that you don't want to persist. Refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-property).